# How do I concatenate strings in 1D Lists inside a 2D list to create a 1D list that has all the concatenated values?

Tags: python, list, concatenation

I am pretty new to Python and I want to combine the lists inside the 2D lists that save into a 1D list. An example is below:

```py
temp = [['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6']]
```

convert to

```py
temp = ['123', '456']
```

Answer (score 7):

Check out list comprehension with join

```
new_list = [''.join(data) for data in temp] # -> ['123', '456']
```

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
temp = [['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6']]

for i in range(len(temp)):
  temp[i] = "".join(temp[i])

print(temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
temp = [*map(''.join, temp)]
```

...